# how to create .desktop file for Solaris 10

Tags: solaris

Hi I have created jar of my application. also i have created .desktop file for fedora it worked fine. but that .desktop file did not work fine for solaris 10. How to create desktop file for mac OS for my jar.

Also I want to set icon in that desktop file

Is there any example?

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few dozen examples in /usr/share/applications in the Solaris OS for the applications shipped as part of the Solaris-bundled GNOME desktop.